Android Bitmap Heap
According to the documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory starting with Android 8.0 Bitmaps are again stored in the native memory instead of Dalvik heap. But doesn't it return all the problems that have existed before Android 3 when Bitmap were stored in the native memory as well? Specifically, from my understanding, as Bitmaps are stored in the native memory again, there can be out of memory issues since large bitmaps do not create memory pressure for GC. Do I understand it wrongly?

OuOfMemory issues can happen either way.  Storing it in Dalvik memory doesn't reduce total memory usage by any meaningful amount, but can have negative effects on the garbage collection algorithm.  I'd trust the OS developers to have measured both and made the right choice.  The memory issue frequency back in the day wasn't due to having it in native memory, it was due to the devices having tiny amounts of RAM.  Bigger RAM and more aggressive killing of background apps is why you don't seill see them.

The real reason to choose dalvik or native memory has to do with how having large allocations effects the gc.  I can see having those large allocations causing unnecessary framentation of the memory pool and causing OOM issues due to that when allocating other large blocks from the dalvik pool.  But I would also trust google's engineers to measure that kind of thing when making this decision

The other cause of OOM on really old devices was that most devices had an OEM set limit on the amount of dalvik heap any one process could take.  128MB was a common limit for a while, and I had an app that would regularly hit it.  If this limit still exists, it's now in the GB range.  So that's another large set of oom issues that just isn't a problem anymore.

@GabeSechan Correct me if I'm wrong please, as far as I understand if bitmap is stored in native heap instead of Dalvik heap, it motivates us to call .recycle() as soon as possible while it wan't mandatory when the bitmap was stored in the Dalvik heap

No, not really.  Bitmap will have a finalizer that calls recycle.  Finalizers are called when the garbage collector is about to free it.  So recycle would be called when its collected, which is equivalent to the behavior if it was in dalvik memory.  Being more aggressive about calling recycle is a good idea for a cache layer, but is probably otherwise unnecessary.

@GabeSechan My concern is that if we do not call recycle aggressively, there is a high chance that GC won't run in time. For example, we create thousands of bitmaps and rely on finalization. In this case almost no memory is used on Dalvik Heap (only bitmap headers are stored there but they are extremely small), and so there is no pressure on Garbage Collector to be run. At the same time we consume a large amount of native memory which isn't cleared until GC runs. And thank you for all your responces

That's a pretty degenerate case-  99% of apps won't have that problem.  I'd question why you're creating that many bitmaps, and if you are you should be using an LRU cache to hold them, and it would be that cache's job to recycle them.  But yes, that would be a good reason to aggressively call recycle.
